Chroot: Write access to an SFTP directory by non-root users?
Task given: Set up an SFTP server for ~100 clients
and fill their ./in directory with pricelists. 
The pricelist per client is updated and maintained
by a different user-account (≠root) in the normal servergroup
(e.g., daisy:myserver).
So far, so working.
How to put the pricelists into the $sftpdir/$sftpuser/in
without using root?
I tried to put the pricelist-generator-user "daisy" into the $sftpgroup, which causes chroot to complain (so "daisy" cannot login by ssh anymore).
Sure, I can create a shadow-directory and a root copy process,
but this will cause different problems.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Should the SFTP user be allowed to modify the price lists?

If not, change the owner of the ./in directories to daisy:
for sftpuser in user1 user2 user3 …
do
    chown daisy "$sftpdir/$sftpuser/in"
done

Or simply
chown daisy "$sftpdir"/*/in

Mode should be 755 or 750.
This must be set up as root (i.e., sudo),
but that’s a one-time preparatory step.

If yes (i.e., if the user is allowed to modify the price lists,
and giving write permission to “daisy” is the only issue),
pick one of the following to do to each in directory:

Chmod them to 777.
Chgrp them to a group that daisy is in (is “myserver” a group? 
is there a “daisy” group, with GID equal to daisy’s UID?)
and chmod them to 775 (or 770).
Give daisy write permission with ACLs.



All these solutions require that
daisy has execute access to the $sftpdir/$sftpuser home directories.


Another approach is to put the price lists somewhere other than the users’ directories, and symlink to them.

Pick a pricelist_directory; perhaps
pricelist_directory="$sftpdir/daisy/pricelists"

and create it. 
It doesn’t have to be parallel to the user directories,
but it must, of course, be within the chroot. 
It should be owned by daisy and readable by the users.

for sftpuser in user1 user2 user3 …
do
    mkdir "$pricelist_directory/$sftpuser"
done

or use some other naming scheme. 
Again, obviously, the users must have access (so mode 755 or 750).
For each SFTP user, do
ln -s "$pricelist_directory/$sftpuser" "$sftpdir/$sftpuser/in"

but using a relative pathname to the per-user price list directory
created in the previous bullet.

This is like option #1 in that
the SFTP user does not have write access to the price lists. 
Unlike options #1 and #2, this does not require that
daisy have execute access to the $sftpdir/$sftpuser home directories.
This might not work as well as the other solutions for some use cases. 
Notably, if the SFTP users have access to shell commands,
they would need to use -L to list their in directories with ls. 
You’ll want to look at any directory-listing command(s)
that they have access to within SFTP.


